# Removing HTML from Web Scrape

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

New to python and trying to learn to web scrape.  I'm currently running into a problem trying to figure out how to remove the html from the final product.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = 'http://web.mta.info/developers/turnstile.html'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

dataFiles = soup.find('div', class_='span-84')
# fullDates = dataFiles.findAll('a')

print(dataFiles)
```

When I run this I get results like:

[block of text including all the html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvHnj.png) (with the html I'm not sure how to post it here where it actually shows up like it does in terminal versus just looking normal here.)

I'm looking for:

Saturday, April 11, 2020
Saturday, April 04, 2020
Saturday, March 28, 2020
Saturday, March 21, 2020

...and so on...

I've tried:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = 'http://web.mta.info/developers/turnstile.html'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

dataFiles = soup.find('div', class_='span-84')

print(dataFiles.text.strip)
```

That produces:

Using just: print(dataFiles.strip) or print(dataFiles.text) produces output: None

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the data stripped of the HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req,utils
url = 'http://web.mta.info/developers/turnstile.html'
html = req.get(url)
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
dataFiles = doc.select('div.span-84')
# # Get links
fullDates = dataFiles.selects('a')
print ([a.text.split(',',1) for a in fullDates])
# print ([(a.href,a.text) for a in fullDates])
# # Completion link
# print ([utils.absoluteUrl(url, a.href) for a in fullDates])
# print(dataFiles.text)
```

Result:

```
[['Saturday', ' April 18, 2020'], ['Saturday', ' April 11, 2020'],...
```

Comment: That worked.  So did my original with a tweak.  Now the text is printing out in one long string with the year attached to the subsequent entry: ex "Saturday, April 18, 2020Saturday, April 11, 2020Saturday, April..." and so on.  Any suggestions for how they can be separated?

Comment: @harrycoin I changed the answer, I don't know if it's what you want.